# calling WCF Services hosted on IIS Server with wsHttpBinding having Message security mode from Ios Device

Tags: wcf-binding, wcf-security

I am calling WCF Service (wsHttpBinding with Message Security mode) from ios device but i am not able to see encrypted request and response .
 while i am calling service from TestClient i can see request and response is encrypted.i want my request and response should be secure on network .
  my configuration in web.config

```
 <wsHttpBinding>
 <binding name="Service.BasicHttp.BindingConfig">
 <security mode="Message"  />  
</binding>
 </wsHttpBinding>

--binding applied on endpoint

<endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="CloudMitoAPI.ICloudMitoService" bindingConfiguration="Service.BasicHttp.BindingConfig"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add some parameter secure parameter in which add both json object and encrypted secure object in your request and then when you send it to server check the parameter object and encrypted secure object with your secret key is it proper or tampered.

Comment: i have another one question regarding session management in wcf. how we can manage session in wcf while we are calling from ios device.

Comment: First of all you need to add

[ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.Allowed)] in ServiceContract

and then in operation Contract you nedd to add 

[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession)] 
public class Service : IService
{
}

Comment: you can check this link 
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dhananjaycoder/instance-management-in-wcf-part-sharp-2/

Comment: is it required to use wsHttpBinding for session management.if yes,how we can configure bindings from ios device because they are calling as restful service.